# Unity3D: How to stop the flickering that occurs when the character stops moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, youtube

I followed this tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7URRg8J6mz8). It took me a while but I've almost converted from movement by arrows to mouse touch . but now I have this problem, there's flickering that occurs when the character stops moving. I looked at the link he sent me but it doesn't work. Please look at this video to show you what I am talking [about](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLczzyq_Ceo). Does anyone knows how to stop the flickering that occurs when the character stops moving? This is my code:

```
private Animator anim;
public float speed = 15f;
private Vector3 target;
private bool touched;


void Start () {
    target = transform.position;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void Update () {
    touched = true;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = 10; // distance from the camera
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        target.z = transform.position.z;
    }



        var movementDirection = (target - transform.position).normalized;

        if (movementDirection.x != 0 || movementDirection.y != 0) {
            anim.SetBool("walking" , true);
            anim.SetFloat("SpeedX" , movementDirection.x);
            anim.SetFloat("SpeedY" , movementDirection.y);

            Vector2 movement = new Vector2(
                speed * movementDirection.x ,
                speed * movementDirection.y);
            movement *= Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Translate(movement);

            if (movementDirection.x < 0) {
                anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX" , -1f);
            }
            else if (movementDirection.x > 0) {
                anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX" , 1f);
            }
            else {
                anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX" , 0f);
            }
            if (movementDirection.y > 0) {
                anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY" , 1f);
            }
            else if (movementDirection.y < 0) {
                anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY" , -1f);
            }
            else {
                anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY" , 0f);
            }
        } else {
        touched = false;
        anim.SetBool("walking" , false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it happens because your character never really stops on the target position.

From what I got from your code, every frame update your character verifies if the variable "target" changed its position, by evaluating if "movementDirection" has any magnitude on x and y axis.

When it does it uses the variable "movement" to calculate the position increment towards the intended destination, right? However, when your character object gets very close to the destination, the increment calculated at "movement" after the line

```
movement *= Time.deltaTime;
```

is too big for the distance left to travel, so your character goes beyond the target position. Another way too put it is:

Imagine your character's speed is 3 (for the sake of this argument). Then you have:

(C is your character, T is the Target)

| C | | | | | | | | T | | | | | | |

then,

| | | | C | | | | T | | | | | | |

then,

| | | | | | | C | T | | | | | | |

and then,

| | | | | | | | T | | C | | | | |

As you can see, its excess speed makes it go through the target position. What will your script do next? It will reverse the movement direction, and so you will have:

| | | | | | C | T | | | | | | | again

and then,

| | | | | | | T | | C | | | | |

and then,

| | | | | | C | T | | | | | | |

And so your character is forever locked in this loop, always changing between those two positions near the target, which produces the flickering effect you see.

*Suggestions:*

1. Changing the way you compute your character's movement, like instead of using Translate, adding a rigidbody and using physics (although I understand you don't want to choose this one)
2. Write an if statement which checks of the character is very close to your target. And if it is, just move it to that position, like

   transform.position = target;
3. Simply reduce your character's speed. This is the least recommendable option, as it might solve the problem now but it might happen again later.

EDIT1: Made clearer my answer in the beginning.

EDIT2: Corrected mistake on my analogy

Comment: Hi :) Did my answer help you? Were you able to fix the problem?